# Nil error when testing Lua code with busted

Tags: lua, lua-busted

I am new to using busted testing framework for Lua, but I wrote two tests. Each one works on their own, there are no errors. But when I run them both (e.g. I don't include --exclude-pattern=name_spec.lua), the one that starts later fails with an error message

> Error -> Nil error
> suite spec/name_spec.lua

The spec folder is where my tests are located. The last busted message before the error happens is ●✱, but I don't know what the star means.

Comment: what is a Nil error? that's not a Lua error message.

Comment: I am not sure, it seems to be a busted specific error, not a Lua error message.